# How to use Windows Phone Camera's CAF feature until maximum sharpness is achieved?

Tags: c#, camera, windows-phone-8.1

So I'm creating my own application that uses the primary Windows Phone Camera. I'd like to implement CAF (Continuous Auto Focusing) whenever I click the Capture button. The camera should be continuously focusing until the image becomes sharp and crisp and it will finally capture the image automatically.

In this website: https://www.microsoft.com/en-xm/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA138457, they are telling that CAF feature is existent in Lumia. I've been searching in MSDN, but I can only see C# samples for auto focus and tap to focus features. None for CAF. Please help me on how to implement it. Without it, most of my images ends up blurry unless I manually tap the screen for focusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. Nevermind. I found an universal application made by Microsoft that has CAF implementation using the MediaCapture.